# How can I store a list or dictionary type into SQL as a single variable?

Tags: c#, sql, types, sqldatatypes

I need to use a data type like list or dictionary in a class.  All of this data needs to be stored into SQL.

Is it possible to use them with SQL directly or do I have to transfer them into other data type like string to use with SQL?

The problem is that I can't guarantee any symbol will never be used in the data, so I don't know how to separate the data to transfer them from string to list.

For example, the data I need to use is: `Dictionary<string, int> topics;` there can be anything in the string key. How can I store this into SQL as one variable?

Comment: Though you _can_ do this in various ways, it will not be a normalized database, failing [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms). In general it is a bad idea of you need to query or join on such a field.

Comment: You should have multiple tables. A simplified example could be... Table1 is similar to an array of pointers to objects. Table2 is similar to an array of object properties - It has a Foreign Key relationship back to Table1 and then multiple records per parent Object; to hold all of the data needed to represent a List or Dictionary. One field in one record should only ever hold one item of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store a serialized (XML) version of an object in SQL server

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the dictioanry to a datatable and pass it as table parameter into the sproc.